# Switch partial based on radio button in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I don't know how to perform this in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I've got two radio buttons of the same group, I wish to switch a partial view based on the current radio button selection. I think I'll have to use js somehow but I don't know how.

Currently I wrote

```
Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("manual").Checked(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "group1" }).Label("Manuale");
Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("guidata").Checked(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "group1" }).Label("Guidata");

<div id="dyn_container"/>
```

But I don't know how to load data and eventually pass a model, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The essence of `RadioButton` is actually an `Input`, so you can use the method of monitoring `Input` changes to determine how to continue to perform the following operations.

Below is my test code, you can refer to it:

View:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="Form_Label"><label for="txType">Select List:</label>  </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("manual").Checked(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "group1",@value = "Manuale" }).Label("Manuale")
            @Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("guidata").Checked(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "group1",@value = "Guidata" }).Label("Guidata")
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="dyn_container"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script >
        $('input:radio[name=group1]').change(function() {
            var url = '/Home/Manuale';
            if ($(this).val() === 'Guidata') {
                url = '/Home/Guidata';
            }
            $("#dyn_container").load(url);
        });
    </script>
```

Then, you can execute the corresponding action in the controller by:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Manuale()
{ 
    return PartialView("_Manuale");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Guidata()
{
    return PartialView("_Guidata");
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

This is caused by inconsistency between your constructor and instantiation, you need to inject `ILogger<_Page1Model>` into the page.

Add this line of code in View:

```
@inject ILogger<_Page1Model> logger1
```

Then `modify Html.PartialAsync`:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_Page1", new _Page1Model(logger1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I have a little bit modified your example (I don't have the original code under my hands so I wrote a new one).

I don't have a controller, using the RazorPages, so currently I've done this way

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
@using Test.Localization
@using Test.Web.Pages
@using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Table
@using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.TagHelpers
@using Volo.Abp.Users
@model Test.Web.Pages.IndexModel
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<TestResource> L
@inject ICurrentUser CurrentUser
@section styles {
<abp-style src="/Pages/Index.css" />
}
@section scripts {
<abp-script src="/Pages/Index.js" />
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="Form_Label"><label for="txType">Select List:</label>  </td>
      <td>
        @Html.RadioButton("group1","HotelGrandPlaza", false)
        @Html.RadioButton("group1","Test", false)
      </td>        
    </tr>
  </table>


  <div id="project" style="display:none">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Page1", new _Page1Model());
  </div>
  <div id="engineering" style="display:none">
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Page2", new _Page2Model());}
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script >
    $('input:radio[name=group1]').change(function() {
 
      if ($(this).val() === 'Test') {
        $("#project").hide();
        $("#engineering").show();
      
      } else {
        {
          $("#project").show();
          $("#engineering").hide();
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

In this case when I switch it works... but problems arrive when I have a constructor with Dependency Injection....

Just with this simple case

```
 public class _Page1Model : PageModel
  {
    private readonly ILogger<_Page1Model> _logger;

    public _Page1Model(ILogger<_Page1Model> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

I can't use the cshtml I've defined before... any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, you can have a try.